# BizTalk.Unexpected data found while looking for: 'Request Information\r\n'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-deployment

I have a flat file schema which parse a file with multiple lines
I made delimiters to get the needed data after a sentence 'Request Information[CR][LF]'.

When I tried to test the project with a file(.txt) it works correctly.
But when I tried to test by POP data from email

I got this error:

> An output message of the component "Flat file disassembler" in receive pipeline "InqueryCardDemo.EmailParserPipleline, InqueryCardDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0522d81e74b224f" is suspended due to the following error: 
>        Unexpected data found while looking for:
>   'Request Information\r\n'
>   The current definition being parsed is Root. The stream offset where the error occured is 0. The line number where the error occured is 1. The column where the error occured is 0. .
>    The sequence number of the suspended message is 1.

```
<xs:element name="Root">`   
  <xs:annotation>` 
    <xs:appinfo>`
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x52 0x65 0x71 0x75 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x20 0x49 0x6E 0x66 0x6F 0x72 0x6D 0x61 0x74 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
     </xs:appinfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing the EmailParserPipeline for the PassThru pipeline and hooking up a send port to dump the message to a file location (filter on receive port name as the message is untyped). Then, inspect the file - does it looks as expected? Try using a hex editor and check for any byte order marks that appear before your 'Request Information'. This might help you diagnose what the problem is; I am not suggesting that it is a solution.

I suspect the POP adapter is adding something to the start of the message, before the token that you are looking for. Once you have identified what that is, you can either: update your flat file schema to consume those tokens, or add a custom pipeline component before the flat file disassembler to manipulate the incoming message so it conforms to the schema.

If the encoding of the message if not utf-8, BizTalk needs to be told what encoding it is, using a byte order mark (BOM). Also see this MSDN question for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atinag/archive/2009/03/18/utf-encoded-message-failing-in-biztalk-2006.aspx

Comment: EmailParserPipeline is the pipeline that I'm using for parsing the flat file.. i can not replace it

Answer (score 0):

Check the message being received either from HAT for BizTalk 2006R2 or from the BizTalk Admin Console if BizTalk 2009 or above.  You may find that it is a Multipart message that you have to accept, and then get the part you want from that and run that through a Pipeline in your Orcherstration to dissasemble.

[POP3 Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546737.aspx)

> The POP3 receive adapter retrieves e-mail from a specified mailbox on a specified POP3 server. By default, the POP3 receive adapter applies MIME processing to the e-mail messages that it downloads and submits these messages to BizTalk Server as multipart BizTalk messages. The POP3 receive adapter can receive and process e-mail in the following formats:
>   Plain text
>   * MIME encoded
>   * MIME encrypted
>   * MIME encoded and signed
>   * MIME encrypted and signed

At my work we avoid using the POP adapter due to it's security issues, we prefer to have an SMTP service running on the BizTalk server that e-mails are forwarded too, and it is configured to write them the .eml files which we then pick up and process via a MIME pipeline and iterate through all the attachments.